# How to deal with 'incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and GBK' exception?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-1.9

I am reading 'Agile Web Development with Rails.3rd'. When finishing the depot application, I input some Chinese character as user name. But I got this error, it seems this has something to do with Ruby1.9

My environment is window xp, Ruby1.9 Rails 2.3.8 and sqlite3.

The following is the detail about this error:

---

Showing app/views/layouts/store.html.erb where line #43 raised:

incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and GBK

Extracted source (around line #43):

40:         <% if flash[:notice] -%>

41:            <%=h flash[:notice] %>

42:         <% end -%>

43:         <%= yield :layout %>

---

Anyone can help me resolve this problem ?

Comment: It would be good if you could provide the full stack trace. Then we could help you solve the problem properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that adding

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

at the beginning is much simpler (and possibly more elegant)

Answer (score 0):

You might try putting this in your environment.rb file:

```
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding.find("UTF-8")
```

You might also be compounding the problem with incorrect console encoding in Windows.  Make sure it is set to Unicode.

Comment: It's seems like this does work. I got nil error when I add Encoding.default_internal = Encoding.find("UTF-8") in my environment.rb file.

Comment: It doesn't work. I got this error
"Internal Server Error
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it! You might have expected an instance of Array. The error occurred while evaluating nil.each "

Comment: Error during failsafe response: "\xE6" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to GBK

Answer (score 0):

it's ridiculous but i had the same issue until

i found that i just had cyrillic "C" in the one of the classes name %)

so maybe it is good advice to check if you not using something like c, a, o, p etc from another keyboard layout(s)